# Получаю пустое значение, когда пытаюсь вывести данные (TypeError)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def index(step=0, names=''):
    response = requests.get(f'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/counterparty?offset={step}',
                            auth=('LOGIN', 'PASSWORD')
                            )
    result = response.json()
    customnames = names

    for i in result['rows']:
        customnames = customnames + i['name'] + " " + "<br>"

    count = int(len(result['rows']))

    if count == 1000:
        index(step + 1000, customnames)
    else:
        return customnames
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The
> function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

В чем может быть проблема? Если `return customnames` заменить на `print(customnames)`, то я получаю в консоли нужные мне данные, а вот на сайт вывести не могу.

### Опишу немного сам код, потому-что протестить его без данных для входа не выйдет

Тут я обращаюсь к странице с данными в формате json, только проблема в том, что там есть ограничение на вывод обьектов - до 1000 шт. Так вот, чтобы получить все объекты, я использую возможность пропуска "offset" и перебирая все это кидаю в одну переменную customnames. В итоге хочу получить полный список элементов.

Comment: почему у вас в функции условия два, а return - один?

Comment: поправил на
   `else: return 1000, customnames`
но ошибка та же

Comment: у вас в if нет return. то есть, если условие выполняется, то вы меняете что-то, но ничего не возвращаете.

Comment: в if запускается функция index, до тех пор пока значение count перестанет быть "1000". как только перестает - return. только вот return пустой почему то. если return поменять на print, то все работает, вот в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил путем добавления `return` перед вызовом функции в `if`

```
if count == 1000:
        return index(step + 1000, customnames)

return customnames
```